# dependencies reference nonexistent child node

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, wagtail

I tried to dockerize my Wagtail Web Application and this error Occurred.
I tried `docker-compose build` there was no errors.
after that i tried `docker-compose up` then this error occurred
I really need help on this error.
Error-

```
49a28e66a331_wagtail_landing_web_1 | django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration home.0002_create_homepage dependencies reference nonexistent child node ('wagtailcore', '0053_locale_model')
49a28e66a331_wagtail_landing_web_1 exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention wagtail versions or if this is an upgrade. But that error sounds like this: https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/2.11.3.html#run-before-declaration-needed-in-initial-homepage-migration

Comment: The Issue I had was ,My Databse was sqlite3 but iwas dockerizing with pastgres.i made that mistake thier.